# How can I place color style and centered on my Multi-column headers?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

If you could give me an example of it I would appreciate it!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bktiQ.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use headerAttributes

**Example:**

```
columns:[{
            headerAttributes: {                  
              style: "text-align: center; background-color: red;"
            },
            title: "Header",
            columns: [{
                field: "FirstName",
                title: "First Name",
                width: "120px"
                },{
                field: "LastName",
                title: "Last Name",
                width: "120px"
                },{
                field: "Country",
                width: "120px"
                },{
                field: "City",
                width: "120px"
                },{
                field: "Title"
            }]
          }]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!